# Importing .swift file into Objective-C file results in Missing Context For Method Declaration Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I am refactoring a few Objective-C ViewControllers and am trying to import a new Controller.swift file into a ViewController.m.  However when I do that and run I get  "Missing Context For Method Declaration" error for every method in the ViewController.m file.

this causes the error:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ContactsController.swift"
```

When I run without the .swift file import everything works fine.  Also I have successfully imported this .swift file into other controllers in the above manner.

However when I change the order of the imports as such it works:

```
#import "ContactsController.swift"
#import "ViewController.h"
```

I have tried to research this, but to no avail.  What are the possible reasons that the import could work in one order and not the other?

**EDIT:**  Switching order does not work, it clears the errors on ViewController.m but throws errors on the swift file.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the obvious.  See my answer below for the correct way to import swift into objective-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahhh..  It's been a loooong day.  Just realized my mistake.  I was trying to import the swift controller directly instead of the Project-Swift.h file, which is the proper way of accessing any swift files in objective-c;

to solve add in your ViewController.m file:

```
#import "<Project Name>-Swift.h"
```